# req: Unknow digest <NULL>

Tags: openssl

I'm in trouble with openssl which says me this : `req: Unknow Digest <NULL>` after entering this : `openssl req -new -key myKey.key - out myCSR.csr`

I'm on Windows 10, using OpenSSL 1.1.0j for x64, I'm running my cmd as administrator and I don't undersand what's wrong...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, a bad space was betwin my - and my out...